# How to Share texts of each element of String Array

Tags: swift3

I am working on a simple iOS app.I have one table view of item lists  and one detail view of this ach item lists.All itemlist and detail list arrays are under the table view class.I want to share each of the detailed texts using button which I put in the detail view.When I try it,the button shares only the first element of the detailed string array.So How can I share every other detail of the texts?

Thanks

Comment: can you share your code

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer! I refer all the detailed string arrays in the detailview.swift file and refer the detailDescriptionTextView.text with the refred items..

` @IBAction func shareButton(_ sender: UIButton) {

```
           let item1 = TableTwo().details[0]
           let item2 = TableTwo().details[1]
           let item3 = TableTwo().details[2]
           let item4 = TableTwo().details[3]
           let item5 = TableTwo().details[4]

    if(detailDescriptionTextView.text == item1){
        let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems:[item1], applicationActivities:nil)
    activityViewController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = self.view
         self.present(activityViewController,animated:true,completion:nil)

 /* activityViewController.excludedActivityTypes = [UIActivityType.airDrop,UIActivityType.copyToPasteboard,UIActivityType.mail,UIActivityType.assignToContact]
 */

    } else if(detailDescriptionTextView.text == item2) {
        let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems:[item2], applicationActivities:nil)
        activityViewController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = self.view
        self.present(activityViewController,animated:true,completion:nil)

    }else if(detailDescriptionTextView.text == item3) {
        let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems:[item3], applicationActivities:nil)
        activityViewController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = self.view
        self.present(activityViewController,animated:true,completion:nil)

    }else if(detailDescriptionTextView.text == item4) {
        let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems:[item4], applicationActivities:nil)
        activityViewController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = self.view
        self.present(activityViewController,animated:true,completion:nil)

    }
    else if(detailDescriptionTextView.text == item5) {
        let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems:[item5], applicationActivities:nil)
        activityViewController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = self.view
        self.present(activityViewController,animated:true,completion:nil)

    }

}
```

`